# Склонение названия города Салехардa

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать:
*я живу в г. Салехард, в городе Салехард* или *я живу в г. Салехарде, в городе Салехарде*?

Answer (score 2):

Географическое наименование, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, станция, поселок, река и т. п., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть СКЛОНЯЕТСЯ, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование. 
Правильно: в г. Нижнем Новгороде, в городе Москве, в г. Санкт-Петербурге, в городе Владивостоке; в деревню Ивановку, у села Воронцовки; на острове Валааме, на мысе Зеленом, у реки Волги, долина ручья Сухого.
Географические названия обычно НЕ СКЛОНЯЮТСЯ в следующих случаях: 
когда внешняя форма названия соответствует форме мн. числа: в городе Великие Луки; 
когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают: с острова Юра, в поселке Всеволодо-Вильва.
Таким образом, ПРАВИЛЬНЫМИ будут варианты: в городе Салехарде, в г.Салехарде.
 Географические наименования, состоящие из одного слова, стоящие после соответствующего родового названия, обычно согласуются с этим названием, если в И.п. ед.ч. оканчиваются не на -У -О -Е -И -Ы; например: в городЕ ПетербургЕ, под городОМ РимОМ и т.д. 
  Географические наименования НЕ согласуются с родовым названием в   а)деловых документах
  б)в географической литературе 
в)в туристических справочниках, часто в официальных сообщениях, так как используются там в исходной форме с целью передания ТОЧНОЙ информации. 
Это норма официально - делового и научного стилей, административно - судебной речи.(Бельчиков Ю.А.Практическая стилистика современного русского языка.-2-е изд.испр и доп.- М.:АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012.- с.266 - 267)
Правильно пишем: житель городА СалехардА, житель г. СалехардА

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить ссылку на источник: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90. А также, если речь идет о написании, стоит заметить, что между сокращением *г.* и *Салехард* должен стоять пробел.

Comment: Конечно, на пробел я внимания не обратила. Спасибо за существенное дополнение.

Comment: Хорошо. А если пишем: житель города Салехард или житель города Салехарда; житель г. Салехард или житель г. Салехарда. Тогда как правильно?

Comment: Извините, Лариса, что не сразу ответила. Сейчас, по- моему, ответ полный.